# Increasing last TR height till parent td height

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario where one table had some tr and other table have less tr's than first one table.Both tables are under td's. In this Scenerio how to increase only last tr height of html table in **%** mode not in **px** mode

**HTML CODE:**

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td style="width:50%">
        <table border="1" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    A
                </td>                
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    B
                </td>                
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    C
                </td>                
            </tr>                 
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">
        <table  border="1" style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    2
                </td>
            </tr>                 
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oo0wwxbk/3/)

Comment: can you show through image representation with expected output?

Comment: @K.B.M Please see updated demo.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oo0wwxbk/5/)** This will expand only last row of right side content

CSS:

```
table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
td {

}
.table {
    display: table;
    height:100%;
}
.cell {

    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;   
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <table border="1" style="width:100%;" class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="cell">
                        <div class="container">Increse this row height till parents td height</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**EDIT**: If you want right column should be equally expanded, you can use like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oo0wwxbk/6/)**

CSS:

```
table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this is what you want!!

Answer (score 0):

use single table and rowspan

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr><td>A</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td><td rowspan="3">3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td></tr>
  <tr><td>E</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i have some other scenerio. My fiddle demo shows what i want..